# How to authenticate my Citrix app with PHP without user input?

Tags: php, citrix

I want to register users to my webinars after they submit a form in my site, this is common practice but I'm having problems authenticating my application.

The problem is that according to the documentation Citrix doesn't support username-password authentication flow (where you put your user and pass in a request and you get a token):
https://developer.citrixonline.com/content/username-password-flow

Instead users need to be directed to a login page to complete their Citrix account credentials, supposedly this can be done by me just once and then save the token, however I couldn't find a method to do it safely, I tried once to save the token and just the next day it was expired. So how can I make sure I get a fresh access token without

I'm using this PHP library which is supposed to simplify the login process (maybe there is some clue in it):
https://github.com/jakir-hayder/Citrix-GoToWebinar-PHP-Library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, read this [primer on OAuth workflow](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/intro_understanding_username_password_oauth_flow.htm) to ensure you have the terms and concepts down pat.  (You can ignore the fact that the example is for SalesForce -- OAuth is all the same.)

Then, you should understand that you're looking for the Citrix Token Request Endpoint, which they happen to call ["Direct Login".](https://developer.citrixonline.com/page/direct-login)

That should let you pass the username/password to get the token to use in subsequent requests.  That what you need?

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that Citrix doesn't support username-password oAuth authentication. I understand that they use a method where you must use the client flow once to get a token and then somehow save it, but I can't figure it out https://developer.citrixonline.com/content/username-password-flow

Comment: This is oAuth, you get the same tokens as you would get with the normal "client" authentication, except you can do this directly from your app, just provide the user's username and password and you get an oAuth token in return.

Comment: @Liso22: Sorry, I don't get you. The Direct Login link I provided takes a username/password pair and returns an OAuth `access_token`.  You remember that token (eg in the session) and send it on subsequent API calls.  The Direct Login link I provided has a complete sample of login with username/password, getting the OAuth `access_token`, and using that token in a "request organizers" API call.  As nearly as I can tell from your OP, this answers your question???

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to collect the API calls that are made to the Citrix API when you log in. Then add some code in your applicaiton to send the same requests, parse the response that has the access token, and dynamically use that token however you've already got it set up in your application.